How does Ktor Client handle deadlock in Bearer Token refresh logic if the refresh request gets a 401 error?
I am using Ktor Client (version 3.0.0) in my Kotlin application and have configured it to use the Bearer Token authorization mechanism. I understand that Ktor automatically attempts to refresh the access token by making an HTTP request whenever a 401 response is encountered during an API call with an expired token.
However, I am curious about how Ktor prevents potential deadlocks in a scenario where the refresh token request itself receives a 401 response (e.g., due to an expired or invalid refresh token).
I’ve tried reading Ktor's official documentation, but I didn’t find specifics about handling errors during the refresh flow.
Any insights or examples would be appreciated!

Ktor is open source, have you tried looking in the source code? I’d assume that auth calls that get 401 simply won’t be retried based on the status code.

actually ktor does not attempt to do a request and retreive a new access token by itself instead the code inside the refreshTokens {} block in the HttpClientConfiguration will be called whenever the client does a request and receives 401 status code.
so the responsibility to refresh the tokens is delegated to you to put in that block
install(Auth) {

    bearer {
        refreshTokens {
          // your logic hear and get the tokens

          //the block has to end with the new tokens whether you retreived the access succesfully
          //or also the refresh failed so they rbooth return to empty string
            BearerTokens(
                refreshToken = "",
                accessToken = ""
            )
        }
    }

   }

